How To add Index on DATETIME column in Informix
I have a query like
SELECT 
patient_id, patient_name 
FROM 
patient_details_tbl 
WHERE 
date(generated_time) between '2024-01-01' and '2024-04-30';

I know if I simply create an index on the generated_time column, then it won't work if we query with date(generated_time).
In Oracle, we have a functional index, which creates an indirect way for this kind of column.
But how to create a functional index in Informix to achieve this?
When I tried this statement, it failed with error -674: Routine (date) can not be resolved.
CREATE INDEX idx_pdt_gen_time ON patient_details_tbl(date(generated_time)) ONLINE;

Please give me the code to achieve this in Informix.
Simplified table schema:
CREATE TABLE patient_details_tbl
(
    patient_id varchar(15),
    patient_name varchar(70),
    gender_id smallint,
    mobile_no integer,
    state_id integer,
    country_id integer,
    generated_date datetime year to fraction
);


It would be helpful if you provided at least an outline schema for the table.  "DATETIME" is ambiguous in Informix: DATETIME YEAR TO YEAR, DATETIME YEAR TO DAY, DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND, DATETIME HOUR TO SECOND, and DATETIME MONTH TO MINUTE are all possible variations (and there are plenty of others too), and the differences are enormous.

CREATE TABLE patient_details_tbl
(
patient_id varchar(15),
patient_name varchar(70),
gender_id smallint,
mobile_no integer,
state_id integer,
country_id integer,
generated_date datetime year to fraction
);
SELECT QUERY:
SELECT
patient_id, patient_name
FROM
patient_details_tbl
WHERE
date(generated_time) between '2024-01-01' and '2024-04-30';
I need to create index for this function based search.

Please add the information to the question — you can edit your own questions.  And please include error messages when you're getting an error.

Check the documentation, there are several restrictions on what can be used for functional indexes on Informix (https://www.ibm.com/docs/fi/informix-servers/12.10?topic=types-using-functional-index). In this case you need to create a wrapper non variant function to use DATE.

Or you could change the WHERE: WHERE generated_time BETWEEN ('2024-01-01')::DATE::DATETIME YEAR TO FRACTION AND ('2024-04-30')::DATE::DATETIME YEAR TO FRACTION .

Informix has functional indexes.  The documentation for CREATE INDEX is extensive.  The section on the index key specification indicates that you can use:
function ( func_col [, func_col]... )
That is, you can invoke a function.  Therefore, the statement you proposed is exactly the syntax to use.
So, for me, the question becomes, "Why are you puzzled about what to do?"
And when I try to create the index, I find out:
SQL -674: Routine (date) can not be resolved.

It would have been helpful if that information had been in the question!  If you are getting an error message, it helps to report what the error(s) are.
That is, I think, a bug in Informix (it is bug number CQ idsdb00114718).  I think it originates from the DATE function existing prior to Informix Universal Server 9.00 (circa 1997).  There are different ways of identifying functions now, and DATE isn't handled like new functions are.  I tried using EXTEND(generated_time, YEAR TO DAY) as the function; it didn't like that.  Trying TO_DATE(generated_time) did not work either (-9700: Routine (to_date) ambiguous - more than one routine resolves to given signature).
I tried creating a function:
CREATE FUNCTION date_from_datetime(dt DATETIME YEAR TO DAY)
    RETURNING DATE WITH(NOT VARIANT);
    RETURN dt;
END FUNCTION;

Without the WITH (NOT VARIANT) clause, it generated an error:
-9848: Functional key part cannot use a variant function (date_from_datetime).  Even with invariant clause, using the ONLINE option to the index statement was rejected with error -21522: No online index build possible, but when that was omitted, the index was created successfully.
This is circumlocuitous (as is the word "circumlocuitous").
